# What format and range does python-soundevice return?

Tags: python, portaudio, python-sounddevice

I recorded some audio with

```
sd.rec(frames=int(duration * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='float32')
```

This returned a numpy array of dtype np.float32.

When recording some clapping (i.e. a fairly loud noise), min and max where around -14.0 and 14.0 respecively. What format is this? It does not appear to correspond to any format listed in [scipy.io.wavfile.read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html). I need to know the range so I can scale this to [-1, 1].